# startActivityForResult in onCreate getting skipped

Tags: android

So I'm really at a loss here. I have my main onCreate try and load a file, if the file doesn't exist I want to call a startActivityForResult to get some input.  My code completely skips over the startActivityForResult,though.  I get nothing from LogCat and code just continues onward.  Calling the startActivityForResult in a handler or something works, but it's not going to work for my app.  Here's my code.

My main onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViews();  
    setListeners();
    Stuffs stuffs = DomUtil.getFullDom(this);
    if (stuffs != null) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SelectType.class), 0);
        addNew(1, null);
    }
    currentScreen = 1;
}
```

The onCreate for SelectType I'm trying to call:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selecttype);
    findView();
    setListeners();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  The only thing I can think is calling startActivityForResult in onCreate, but I've seen tutorials where it's done.  What's going on here?

Comment: How do you know it's not being called or the activity isn't started? Is it only when you're in the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure that `stuffs` can be `null`?

Comment: @Falmarri - Yes I know it's not being called because my debugger skips right over it.  I have breakpoints everywhere.  The SelectType class is supposed to load a simple view with a spinner and a button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

startActivityForResult() is not supposed to return a result; it starts the indicated activity and continues on. When the other activity finishes with a result, your onActivityResult() method will be called with the result. The activities execute asynchronously.

Comment: Right, I know.  I have an onActivityResult() method back on my main. The SelectType class loads a simple view with a spinner and a button. It functions correctly if I bind it to say a button press or something  while the main view is fully loaded, but for some reason it's skipping it now.

Comment: Thank you for wording it the way you did, I understand the problem.  Now to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class TestActivityforResultsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private final int PICK = 1;
int no1 = 30,no2 = 40;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Number1 = "+no1);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Number2 = "+no2);
}

public void startActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(view.getContext(), ResultScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra("no1", no1);
    intent.putExtra("no2", no2);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);       
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      
    int str = data.getIntExtra("YourResults", 10);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText("Result = "+str);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setText("Result = "+str);
}  
}
```

> resulClass

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ResultScreen extends Activity{
int resul =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_screen);     
    System.out.println("Read This Class...."); 
    int no1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("no1", 0);
    int no2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("no2", 0);
    resul = no1+no2;
}

public void setResults(View view) {


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(view.getContext(), TestActivityforResultsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("YourResults", resul);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
}
}
```