# Why does the next instruction execute instantly?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm very new in Android and I have a problem, please take a look at the following code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("Save File")
  .setMessage("Do you want to save to a file ?")
  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          // Ask user for a file name to save the text in the text editor.
          PreSaveFile();

          // Clear text editor. 
          // This is executed immediately and it does not wait until PreSaveFile() ends.
          CleanEditor(et);
        }
    })
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        CleanEditor(et);
    }
})
```

The problem is that second call, `CleanEditor(et)`, does not wait until `PreSaveFile()` ends, so when I choose a file name to save what I have in the text editor, `CleanEditor(et)` erased text editor so nothing can be saved.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: What does PreSaveFile() do?  Can you post the code, and how you know that it is not waiting for the function to complete?

Comment: private void PreSaveFile() {
     EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     if (et.length() == 0) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Editor is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
          if (textFile.length() == 0) {
      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileChooser.class);     
      Bundle myData = new Bundle();
   myData.putString("textFile", "");
   i.putExtras(myData);
   startActivityForResult(i, 1);
     } else { SaveFile(); }
 }

Show a file browser so you can choose a file to write the content of the text editor in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll post your PreSaveFile() function so that it is a little more readable:

```
private void PreSaveFile() { 
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    if (et.length() == 0) { 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Editor is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
    if (textFile.length() == 0) { 
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileChooser.class); 
        Bundle myData = new Bundle(); 
        myData.putString("textFile", ""); 
        i.putExtras(myData); 
        startActivityForResult(i, 1); 
    } else { 
        SaveFile(); 
    } 
}
```

I'd like to make two points here:

1) Have you checked to make sure your code is following the execution path that you're assuming it is?  In particular, have you checked to see that testFile.length() is indeed 0 so that the code enters the if() rather than the else()?

2) **More importantly**, startActivityForResult starts the activity to execute **asynchronously**  as indicated in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982812/startactivityforresult-in-oncreate-getting-skipped).  Any code that you want to execute **after** the result has been obtained should be placed inside of the `onActivityResult()` callback, refer to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351555/synchronous-startactivityforresult-waiting-for-activity-to-complete).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If PreSaveFile shows a dialog to input file name, it will not wait for the dialog to dismiss and will continue executing, an so PreSaveFile finishes and CleanEditor is executed.

You have to add a listener to the dialog created PreSaveFile() and inside that listener you call CleanEditor(et);

Comment: So, this is java works ?, it's not synchronous ?
It break the logic of a program, because you can't call function B until function A has finished.
I can't create a listener and inside it call CleanEditor because not always CleanEditor must be called.

Comment: If CleanEditor must not always be called, then why is it the very next function call after PreSaveFile()?  That means it will always be called after PreSaveFile() terminates